# What could be causing my wp_query pagination to break?

Tags: categories, wp-query

I'm using categories and wp_query to create an "advanced search" feature on [my website](http://www.barbadospropertylist.com/advanced-search/). It was working great until recently I noticed that the pagination was broken. The following 2 links should demonstrate the problem:

On page 1 I get 185 results:

> http://www.barbadospropertylist.com/?cat%5Boffer%5D=24&cat%5Btype%5D=-1&cat%5Blocation%5D=-1&cat%5Bbedrooms%5D=-1&cat%5Bfurnishings%5D=-1&budget=1000000&cat%5Bparish%5D=-1&cat%5Bagent%5D=-1&cat%5Bbathrooms%5D=-1&submit=Advanced+Search

But on subsequent pages the query string breaks:

> http://www.barbadospropertylist.com/page/2/?cat%5Boffer%5D=24&cat%5Btype%5D=-1&cat%5Blocation%5D=-1&cat%5Bbedrooms%5D=-1&cat%5Bfurnishings%5D=-1&cat%5Bparish%5D=-1&cat%5Bagent%5D=-1&cat%5Bbathrooms%5D=-1&budget=1000000&submit=Advanced+Search

You should see the second link redirect to:

> http://www.barbadospropertylist.com/page/2/?budget=1000000&submit=Advanced%20Search

What with recent upgrades to WordPress I have no idea what might be causing this. Any pointers would be very, very welcome! I've been trying to figure this one out all day. :)

Here is my query code:

```
    query_posts(
    array_merge(
        wp_query->query,
        array(
            'category__and' => $pladvsearchcatids,
            'meta_key' => 'price',
            'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
            'meta_compare' => '<=',
            'meta_value' => $plbudget,
            'order' => 'DESC'
        )
    )
);
```

Just noticed something really strange. When I download my site and work locally the problem goes away. The query string is not redirected on page 2 and paging through the results works as expected.

Comment: Would be extra nice to see the query arguments of this advanced search feature.

Comment: Please post some code on how you are querying the database, and displaying pagination.

Comment: Added the query code...

Comment: What is `$pladvsearchcatids`?

Comment: An array of categories.

Comment: When are you calling that `query_posts`? If its before $wp_the_query and conditionals are set, then the canonical redirect would discard all the unused query variables. Also, it should be $wp_query, not wp_query, and you need to global it before using.

Comment: Wordpress $paged on query_posts?
Check the note [in here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts#Pagination)

Comment: I'm calling query_posts in header.php of my theme. And only once an advanced search is requested.

Answer (score 2):

This might happen because you need to include the pagination information when you run custom queries with query_posts. Because custom query_post commands ignore any default values of the query_posts command. Here is an example of a query i have used to solve this problem in a simpler case (just to exclude a single category from the query):

```
   <?php
         if ( is_home() ) {
            $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
            query_posts("cat=-19&paged=$paged");
         }
    ?>
```

Here is an example of how you can include this in your query. Don't know if this works for you, try it out and give me feedback. :)

```
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

    query_posts(
    array_merge(
        $wp_query->query,
        array(
            'category__and' => $pladvsearchcatids,
            'meta_key' => 'price',
            'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
            'meta_compare' => '<=',
            'meta_value' => $plbudget,
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'paged' =>  $paged
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: This didn't work for me.

Comment: Have you tried making the query simpler? Try taking out some of the variables or just set some variable directly into the query to get some further information about where the query breaks.

Comment: My point is, there might be multiple issues causing the pagination to break. I'm pretty sure you need to include pagination information in a custom $wp_query

Comment: No I haven't tried that. It was working fine up until 3.3.1. Sounds like I should start over and build this feature from scratch.

Comment: That might actually be simpler, but if you find the point that is causing the pagination to fail, please let us know, i need to build a feature like this myself pretty soon.

Comment: The odd thing is that pagination is working fine on my local dev environment. Just seems to fail online.

Comment: Have you checked if you have some sort of PHP limitations? like safemode on? Or something similar on the online server? And have you tried limiting the number of results to something like 20 at a time? The problem might be that the script takes to long to execute on the webserver.

Comment: I will check that, but it certainly used to work well before and nothing has really changed on the server.

Answer (score -1):

Please try the following code:

```
$result = query_posts(
    wp_parse_args(
        $GLOBALS['wp_query']->query,
        array(
            'category__and' => $pladvsearchcatids,
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'price',
                    'value' => $plbudget,
                    'compare' => '<='
                )
            ),
            'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
            'order' => 'DESC',
            'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1
        )
    )
);
// Check the output/query result:
echo '<pre>'; print_r( $result ); echo '</pre>';
```

Note, that your `orberby` value accepts only numeric values. You could try `meta_value` instead, if your output are (eventually) strings. In this case, the `compare` statement of `<=` won't work.

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work. In fact, it seem to really screw up my results. The first link I posted in the question now only returns 3 results. :)

Comment: No reason for downvoting before a result is here. What's your settings for posts per page in the admin-settings-page?

Comment: Posts per page is set to 14.

Comment: Are you sure, that `$plbudget` is an `integer` and not a `string`? If that's the case, it can't work.

Comment: Sorry for down-vote, perhaps unnecessary. However, your code did break my ordering.

Comment: I think $plbudget is a string.

Comment: Yea, it did break. But as you got non-default stuff, I'm unable to test the code without your data plus we got no solution so far. About the `string/int`: Just `var_dump/var_export` the meta data. This shows us what type it is. Hint: Loop through the `$result` and call `var_dump( get_post_custom( $single_result->ID ) );`.

Comment: I'm getting the $plbudget from the URL parameter. Almost certain that would be a string.

Comment: Why are you getting from an url? I guess we're pretty misslead. You should show us exactly how your data looks like (see code in previous comment) and how your setup looks like.